# Angular async pipe not working after map observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-datatable

I'm using `ngx-datatable` and I have data source with `string` or `Observable<string>` values.

Here is a part of html template:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let condition of row.conditions">
  <span *ngIf="isObservable(condition)">{{displayConditionsFromObservable(condition) | async }}</span>
  <span *ngIf="!isObservable(condition)">{{displayConditions(condition)}}</span>
</ng-container>
```

In the `isObservable` case data is fetched from the service.

Here is the code of function which is responsible for this data:

```js
displayConditionsFromObservable(condition: Condition): any {
  const obs = condition.value as Observable<string>;

  return obs;
}
```

And this code works properly, but I want to tranform this data, so I use `rxjs pipe`

```js
displayConditionsFromObservable(condition: Condition): any {
  const obs = condition.value as Observable<string>;

  return obs.pipe(map(it => `Changed data ${it}`));
}
```

After adding `pipe` to `Observable` nothing is displayed in the table.

I tried to use different `rxjs operators` but I couldn't manage to display the data.

Comment: is there an error in the console?

Comment: can you type the return of the function to ```Observable<any>``` in stead of ```any``` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if it works in the first case it should also work in the second case.
but maybe `condition.value` is not an Observable

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your code should work fine. Since it's a display issue, perhaps it has something to do with your component's change detection strategy?

Comment: Poking in the dark, but i would assume that your original observable is actually a subject. There are cases where a map actually Breaks the subject behavior and it does not emit immediately. But as other said,might be the change detection strategy as well.